# Getting non-ASCII characters to work in Ren'Py functions

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, renpy

I'm translating a Ren'Py game, which involves redefining a function that converts numbers to written-out words in a particular language. Those strings are then handled and inserted into the game text by the main code of the game (which I can't modify).

My problem is that when I return strings that contain non-ascii characters like `ö` or `ü`, the game throws an exception when it gets to that point.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-4: unexpected end of data
```

Using character codes like `\uC3B6` throws no exception, but I end up with a placeholder box instead of the character I want.

Is there any way to make the function return these characters properly without having access to the remaining code?

Comment: Always post the **full** traceback. What version of python are you using? Are you passing unicode strings or bytes strings? What is the output of `print(repr(mystring))`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I have very little experience with Python (I didn't even know about there being different string types)... and while trying to figure all this out, I just managed to find a solution myself.^^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong escape character and the wrong hex codes. And I had to use unicode strings. `u'\xF6'` and `u'\xFC'` work perfectly fine for the two characters I was trying to get.